# Google Cloud Speech to Text API Issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, microphone, google-cloud-speech

Currently im using google cloud speech to text API for transcribing audio from microphone ("ta-IN" was the language used). It was working fine. But before a couple of days, Only "en-US" is working, Rest of the languages are not working. How to solve this?

```
"""Google Cloud Speech API sample application using the streaming API.

NOTE: This module requires the additional dependency `pyaudio`. To install
using pip:

    pip install pyaudio

Example usage:
    python transcribe_streaming_mic.py
"""

# [START speech_transcribe_streaming_mic]

import queue
import re
import sys

from google.cloud import speech

import pyaudio

# Audio recording parameters
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = int(RATE / 10)  # 100ms


class MicrophoneStream:
    """Opens a recording stream as a generator yielding the audio chunks."""

    def __init__(self: object, rate: int = RATE, chunk: int = CHUNK) -> None:
        """The audio -- and generator -- is guaranteed to be on the main thread."""
        self._rate = rate
        self._chunk = chunk

        # Create a thread-safe buffer of audio data
        self._buff = queue.Queue()
        self.closed = True

    def __enter__(self: object) -> object:
        self._audio_interface = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self._audio_stream = self._audio_interface.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            # The API currently only supports 1-channel (mono) audio
            channels=1,
            rate=self._rate,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=self._chunk,
            # Run the audio stream asynchronously to fill the buffer object.
            # This is necessary so that the input device's buffer doesn't
            # overflow while the calling thread makes network requests, etc.
            stream_callback=self._fill_buffer,
        )

        self.closed = False

        return self

    def __exit__(
        self: object,
        type: object,
        value: object,
        traceback: object,
    ) -> None:
        """Closes the stream, regardless of whether the connection was lost or not."""
        self._audio_stream.stop_stream()
        self._audio_stream.close()
        self.closed = True
        # Signal the generator to terminate so that the client's
        # streaming_recognize method will not block the process termination.
        self._buff.put(None)
        self._audio_interface.terminate()

    def _fill_buffer(
        self: object,
        in_data: object,
        frame_count: int,
        time_info: object,
        status_flags: object,
    ) -> object:
        """Continuously collect data from the audio stream, into the buffer.

        Args:
            in_data: The audio data as a bytes object
            frame_count: The number of frames captured
            time_info: The time information
            status_flags: The status flags

        Returns:
            The audio data as a bytes object
        """
        self._buff.put(in_data)
        return None, pyaudio.paContinue

    def generator(self: object) -> object:
        """Generates audio chunks from the stream of audio data in chunks.

        Args:
            self: The MicrophoneStream object

        Returns:
            A generator that outputs audio chunks.
        """
        while not self.closed:
            # Use a blocking get() to ensure there's at least one chunk of
            # data, and stop iteration if the chunk is None, indicating the
            # end of the audio stream.
            chunk = self._buff.get()
            if chunk is None:
                return
            data = [chunk]

            # Now consume whatever other data's still buffered.
            while True:
                try:
                    chunk = self._buff.get(block=False)
                    if chunk is None:
                        return
                    data.append(chunk)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            yield b"".join(data)


def listen_print_loop(responses: object) -> str:
    """Iterates through server responses and prints them.

    The responses passed is a generator that will block until a response
    is provided by the server.

    Each response may contain multiple results, and each result may contain
    multiple alternatives; Here we
    print only the transcription for the top alternative of the top result.

    In this case, responses are provided for interim results as well. If the
    response is an interim one, print a line feed at the end of it, to allow
    the next result to overwrite it, until the response is a final one. For the
    final one, print a newline to preserve the finalized transcription.

    Args:
        responses: List of server responses

    Returns:
        The transcribed text.
    """
    num_chars_printed = 0
    for response in responses:
        if not response.results:
            continue

        # The `results` list is consecutive. For streaming, we only care about
        # the first result being considered, since once it's `is_final`, it
        # moves on to considering the next utterance.
        result = response.results[0]
        if not result.alternatives:
            continue

        # Display the transcription of the top alternative.
        transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript

        # Display interim results, but with a carriage return at the end of the
        # line, so subsequent lines will overwrite them.
        #
        # If the previous result was longer than this one, we need to print
        # some extra spaces to overwrite the previous result
        overwrite_chars = " " * (num_chars_printed - len(transcript))

        if not result.is_final:
            sys.stdout.write(transcript + overwrite_chars + "\r")
            sys.stdout.flush()

            num_chars_printed = len(transcript)

        else:
            print(transcript + overwrite_chars)

            # Exit recognition if any of the transcribed phrases could be
            # one of our keywords.
            if re.search(r"\b(exit|quit)\b", transcript, re.I):
                print("Exiting..")
                break

            num_chars_printed = 0

        return transcript


def main() -> None:
    """Transcribe speech from audio file."""
    # See http://g.co/cloud/speech/docs/languages
    # for a list of supported languages.
    language_code = "ta-IN"  # a BCP-47 language tag

    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=RATE,
        language_code=language_code,
    )

    streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
        single_utterance=False, config=config, interim_results=False
    )
    with MicrophoneStream(RATE, CHUNK) as stream:
        audio_generator = stream.generator()
        requests = (
            speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
            for content in audio_generator
        )
        responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)

        # Now, put the transcription responses to use.
        listen_print_loop(responses)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        main()
# [END speech_transcribe_streaming_mic]
```

Kindly help me sort this thing out!

When lang parameter is given en-US its working, Rest of the languages are not working.

Comment: What part of your code is not working? What are the error messages? Do you have a stack trace or other debugging information? Edit your post to clearly define a problem with relevant error and debugging information.

Comment: Infinite loading happens. No bug, no exception error at all! It keeps on listening..

Comment: Please be specific when you describe something. What does "infinite loading" mean?

Comment: Executing the above given code with en-US works fine. it prints the transcript of voice spoken on mic in console. When some other languages given, nothing happens in console. the mic is keep on listening.

Comment: To viewers, the API is working when the "model" parameter is added in "RecognitionConfig" with appropriate model suitable for language used. In my case I used "latest_short"..